# How can i check time taken for each screen on my android app

Tags: android

My PM wants me to test that how much time my android app is taking on GPRS/edge/3g when i navigate in app.
Is there any tool that i can use as he want me to use a tool that we can run.

he wants that when we use  our app on mobile network how much time each page takes to load.. 
Please help!!

Comment: What do you mean with "page"? Are you talking about web pages?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tool provided by Android itself to optimize and monitor Application Performance

One of the tool is [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html)

Documentation:

> Traceview is a graphical viewer for execution logs saved by your
> application. Traceview can help you debug your application and profile
> its performance.

Android also provides [Device Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) is available which comprises of several tools including TraceView

Documentation:

> Android Device Monitor is a stand-alone tool that provides a graphical user interface for several Android application debugging and analysis tools.

Give it a try to these tools

Also if you want to find out how to improve performance, go through following blog I usually refer to optimize application performance

http://opensignal.com/blog/2013/07/30/40-developer-tips-for-android-optimization/

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to log the time that is spend in some method call you could use [TimingLogger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html). With that you could log every network request and how long it takes to receive the network response.